# Using SQL check to see if an ID in Table A exists in Table B. If that ID exists in Table B return corresponding value

Tags: sql, case, teradata, multiple-tables

I have a table call it Table A. Table A with an ID column ID1 associated with a row. That table looks like the following:

| ID1 |
| --- |
| A1.0 |
| B2.0 |
| C3.0 |
| A1.0 |
| ... |

I have a second table call it Table B that has an ID and a corresponding value. That table looks like the following:

| Value | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | A1.0 |
| Banana | B2.0 |
| Peach | C3.0 |
| ... | ... |

I want to run a SQL query to see if the ID in Table A has a match to an ID in Table B. If there is a match return the Value in Table B as a new column in Table A. I was thinking of using some form of a CASE. The final table A should look like the following:

| ID1 | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1.0 | Apple |
| B2.0 | Banana |
| C3.0 | Peach |
| A1.0 | Apple |
| ... | ... |

Comment: This is a left join or possibly just an inner join. You could also write it as a scalar subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to skip any values in TableA that do not have a corresponding value in TableB, an INNER JOIN would suffice:

```
SELECT 
    TABLEA.ID1,
    TABLEB.Value
FROM
    TABLEA 
    INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID1 = TableB.ID
```

If you *do* want to show values existing in TableA, that do not exist in TableB, change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    TABLEA.ID1,
    TABLEB.Value
FROM
    TABLEA 
    LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID1 = TableB.ID
```

If you have a situation like prior to the edit, where multiple columns exist in tableA that can correspond with the ID in TableB, you could go with Andrew's suggestion of using `OR` in the join condition.

Comment: If a value does not exist I would want to return NULL

Comment: @Scott - That's exactly what a LEFT JOIN would accomplish. I added the full example to the answer. But the difference is literally just changing `INNER` to `LEFT`.

Comment: If it worked, then please consider upvoting and accepting it as an answer. That would help people who end up finding the question through Google to see what solved it for you. Thank you.